# Log4J doesn't look like to work with sudo

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, debian, log4j

I've got a Java application and I'm trying to run this application on Linux boot. Problem is that Log4J doesn't look like to work with commands "runuser", "sudo" and "su".
Every single time, I'm getting an error:

```
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
(30/05/2020-15:16:11.825) [FATAL] Unable to log file
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at me.inao.discordbot.util.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:28)
        at me.inao.discordbot.Main.loadConfig(Main.java:65)
        at me.inao.discordbot.Main.starter(Main.java:46)
        at me.inao.discordbot.Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

App is Open-Sourced, so here is my full source: https://github.com/onemoreplays/bufferBot
Does this happen to someone else? Is that because of my bad programming habits or it's a bug somewhere else?
Thank you for any help.
Jakub.

Answer (score 0):

`Main#getApi()` method is executed in the `Logger` constructor. But, according to the stacktrace, current logger is instantiated in the `Main#loadConfig()` method (Main.java, line 46), before `api` field is actually initialized (Main.java, line 47).

Update:
Described issue in Logger constructor hides an original exception, thrown in try..catch block of the `loadConfig` method. The most likely cause of the original issue is access to 'config.json' file under the root. But the best way is to fix NPE in the Logger class, so you will see stack trace of the original exception.

Also it could be a good idea to decouple Logger from your business logic.

Comment: Problem is this app runs completely fine when I switch to the user "dbot" using su and then run launch from that user manually.
Screenshot: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/699931918749139045/716279511154556969/unknown.png